# Check form for similar value before submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, input

Is there anyway to check if a similar value  exist in an input box

EX:

```
<form>
  USER 1
  <input name="user1" value="bla1">
  <input name="pass1" value="ple1">
  <input name="email1" value="foo1@yy.cc">

  USER 2
  <input name="user2" value="bla2">
  <input name="pass2" value="ple1">
  <input name="email2" value="foo2@yy.cc">

  USER 3
  <input name="user3" value="bla1">
  <input name="pass3" value="pla3">
  <input name="email3" value="foo2@yy.cc">

  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

The verification will trigger when the form is submitted, it will alert the user and add a class to both the input with the similar value. All the input fields starts at blank and the user should input the values. All fields should only be compared to its type USER,PASS, and EMAIL

Comment: are you using php or javascript???, you could use if statements in either one... if(item 1 == item2) { then alert something }

Comment: I dunno why you need this form. what purpose?

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok for(var counter = 1; counter <= $('#counter-user').val();counter++){
        x = 1
     while(x <= $('#counter-user').val()){
      
      if( counter != x){
       
       if($('input[name="user'+ counter +'"]').val() = $('input[name="user'+ x +'"]').val()){
        $('input[name="user'+ counter +'"]').addClass('validation-failed');
        $('input[name="user'+ x +'"]').addClass('validation-failed');
       }
        
      }
      x++;
      alert(x)
     }
     
     
   }

Comment: @lv0gun9 creating multiple users that are supposedly unique to one another.

Comment: @Careen read tag "JQUERY"

Comment: @link i see that but by the question not too sure where the process was intended to go....

Comment: @Link I have same question Careen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a wee [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrbm8meg/1/) for you.

Basically it just loops through every element in the form, finds any with similar names, and if they have the same value it marks them both. This is a little inefficient as it compares A with B, then B with A, but still works well.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var ok = true,
        $form = $(this),
        $inputs = $(this).find('input')
    $inputs.removeClass('error')
    $inputs.each(function() {
        var $src = $(this)

        //Get the name of the element, and strip off the number
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace(/[0-9]/g,'')

        //Filter the inputs down to only the ones whose name starts the same
        $inputs.not(this).filter('[name^="' + name + '"]').each(function() {
           if($src.val() == $(this).val()) {
                ok = false
                $(this).addClass('error')
                $src.addClass('error')
            }
        })
    })
    if(!ok) event.preventDefault()
})
```